# activity and intent basics

Tags: java, android

can someone explain this code

1) what class startActivity() belongs to

2) what are these arguments in intent

3) who pass the view object in onclick(View view)

here Second.class is next activity

```
public void onClick(View view) {   
    Intent intent=new Intent(View.getContext(),Second.class);  
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: You should reference the Intent docs for questions about `Intent`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent ; and `Activity` for `startActivity` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `startActivity()` belongs to the parent class of other activities: `android.app.Activity`

2) The first argument of the Intent's contructor you're using is a context of the application package implementing the current activity. The second argument is the class that is to be used for the intent

3) The `view` argument is passed in `onclick(View view)` by the Activity's main thread. This is handled internally by Android OS